# want to completely dealloc object's memory

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

In one controller I add other controller's view in the following way:

```
objSecondController = nil;
objSecondController = [[SecondController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondController"
                                                        bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:objSecondController.view];
```

In view did load of objSecondController I do the following:

```
self.pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] init];     
[self.view addSubview:self.pdfView.view];
```

and then I specify pdf according to its methods

In one of button clicks method for changing the pdf I do the following:

```
if(self.pdfView)
{
    [self.pdfView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.pdfView release];
    self.pdfView = nil;
}
```

and then again do:

```
self.pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] init];     
[self.view addSubview:self.pdfView.view];
```

and then I specify pdf according to its methods

Now self.pdfView is third party library, whenever I use self.pdfview its retain count increases automatically so when I release self.pdfView its retain count does not become 0 and so it does not dealloc though I release them.

The pdf are as large as 25MB and 39 MB so as the previous memory does not dealloc totally it crashes due to excess memory.

What should I do so self.pdfView releases memory completely, so it does not create problem while loading other large pdf?

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRR?  You're going to have to show some code; chatting about it won't help solve it.

Comment: I have edited my question. I do not use ARC

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have properly implemented setter/getter methods, then you are retaining the `pdfView` one-too-many-times with this code:

```
self.pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:self.pdfView.view];
```

This is because the setter for `pdfView` will also call `retain`.

You need to use:

```
self.pdfView = [[[PDFView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.pdfView.view];
```

Also remove this statement, as it's not necessary:

```
[self.pdfView release];
```

As this is sufficient:

```
self.pdfView = nil;
```

I would suggest allocating `pdfView` in the `init` method and releasing it in `dealloc` and just changing the PDF within the view in both `viewDidLoad` and whenever the *Change PDF* button is pressed.  There is no need to `init`/`addSubview`/`removeFromSuperview`/`release` the `PDFView` object whenever its content should change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is that library only supports one method for changing pdf which is something like 'initwithpdf' so I need to initialize overtime. Also on button click for changing pdf, dealloc will not be called, and in dealloc I will not be able to release or make that object nil as I am using the same variable for loading different pdfs, so at that time other pdf must have been loaded. I am trying with auto release as you suggested.

Comment: @Vibhooti That's a shame.  Sounds like you need to use the method you have already implemented then.

Comment: But the library only uses that method for changing pdf, and requires that everything related to the library should become nil before changing to other pdf